# How to use ngModelChange with Pipe

Tags: angular

Here is the follow Html input :

```
<input matInput [ngModel]="myDates[i][month]|number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="myDates[i][month]=$event" (blur)="singleUpdate('cargo', j + 1, myDates[i][month], i)">
```

in this case, when I input 1, the result become 1.00

However when I input 12, the result become 1.002 not 12.00

how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Comment: Can you please provide code for `singleUpdate` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the output you are getting is correct, because the `number` pipe tries to format the input as soon as it gets the value within the `ngModel`.

And also `ngModelChange` will not help you in this case. It will output the same.

You got to utilize `blur` event and [**DecimalPipe**](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe). Also you can use two way binding for `ngModel` with `[()]` syntax.

template

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myDates" (blur)="formatNumber()">
```

component.ts

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private decPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

formatNumber() {
    this.myDates = this.decPipe.transform(this.myDates, '1.2-2');
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pipe-ng-format?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Comment: @IVEjai Please make some effort to understand the demo and change your code accordingly. Simply copy pasting the error will not make any sense here. Also read the description provided.

Comment: your function works, but I need to send 1.4-4 to the back end and display 1.2-2 to front end, is that ok to set pipe in ts ?

Comment: You can do that, just tweak the format to 1.4-4 using the same method on submit event.